# BMW 330Xi tire rim broken

Tags: tires, bmw

New tire started leaking air just to find out that the tire is alright and the air taking pin is also fine. the rim is cracked from inside. I've no clue how that can happen.

Also, my mechanic is asking me to replace that whole thing which costs about 800 bucks :-(

Can someone not weld that thing? Is it something that I can approach/ask around?

Comment: Should be able to be welded ... People have it done all the time. Especially if the crack is on the inside, cleanup should be a breeze.

Comment: Thanks @Paulster2 will try to find someone who can do it.

Comment: I was also assuming the rim is aluminum? I doubt a steel rim would cost that much and magnesium hasn't been used in quite some time (cannot weld magnesium rim ... would burn everything to the ground ... think China Syndrome).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I researched and found that its not good to weld the rim as it tends to break pretty easily.

So I went ahead and ordered one from hubcaphaven. Seems like nice guys.

Will see.

cheers.